# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES), spring-servlet, bean entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

like in topic, but if I will do just persistence.xml file in META-INF with unitName, and do that by this, then everything is good, and my sql query is working, and connection is open.
Here is my view of my project:

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKnZP.jpg)

Here is code where I invoke method, my HomeController.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("/")
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/dam"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(Model model) 
{
    userDao.getUserByUserId("2");
    //employeeDao.getAllEmployees();
    return "listEmployeeView";
}
}
```

Here is UserDao.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDao {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public UserModel getUserByUserId(String userId) {
    UserModel user = null;
    //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("movie-unit");
    //entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<UserModel> cq = cb.createQuery(UserModel.class);
    Root<User> userRoot = cq.from(User.class);
    cq.multiselect(
            userRoot.get("firstName"),
            userRoot.get("middleName"),
            userRoot.get("lastName"),
            userRoot.get("email"),
            userRoot.get("userId"),
            userRoot.get("password")
            );
    cq.where(cb.equal(userRoot.get("userId"), userId));
    TypedQuery<UserModel> q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    user = q.getSingleResult();
    System.out.print(user.getUserId()+"&"+user.getPassword());
    return user;
}

}
```

here is web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Hibernate JPA Hello World Application</display-name>

<!-- Configuration file for the root application context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and here is spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.demo" />

<!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers by registering 
     two beans - DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- This resolves messages from resource bundles for different locales --> 
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<!-- To validate the posted add employee form -->
<bean id="employeeValidator" class="com.howtodoinjava.demo.validator.EmployeeValidator" />

<!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory; 
     rather than application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.howtodoinjava.demo.model" />
  <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
       Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
<property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baza" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="root" />

   </bean>

    <!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access. 
    JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing      multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
        <bean id="transactionManager"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
   </bean>
<!-- responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power     annotation-driven transaction management; 
    such as when @Transactional methods are invoked -->
   <tx:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

Like I said, if I do entitymanager and entitymanagerfactory in java code which is commented here in UserDao.java with persistence.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="movie-unit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baza" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

then everythings works fine.
In mysql server I have privileges like this:
Any %   --  USAGE
Any localhost   no password USAGE
root    127.0.0.1   no password ALL PRIVILEGES
root    ::1 no password ALL PRIVILEGES
root    localhost   with password   ALL PRIVILEGES

Where is problem?

Comment: Your application is using the root user??!  And the root password is `root`?!?!???!?

Comment: without password, or whit other password is still the same problem. Problem probably is not in this what you're saying

Comment: try changing `<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/baza" />` to `<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/baza" />`

Comment: I found error lol - i don't know how is this even possible, but althought I build (clean install) this maven project, in webapps folder in tomcat in spring-servlet.xml there are bad credential, like jdbc:mysql://localhost/test, and password is like 'password' (just like in the beginning because this is code from some tutorial). How is thie possible??